# hide buttons based on query string

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small forum app with **Laravel** and **Vue** and currently i'm adding filter buttons to fetch threads based on the filter button.

For example, in a **Vue component**,  i have the following button, which essentially makes a get request to the back-end  and fetches the threads created by the authenticated user

```
<a href="/threads?myThreads=1"> My Threads </a>
```

But in addition to the button above i have other filters as well

1. Threads i have replied to
2. Threads that were created 7 days ago

However, i want to hide the clicked buttons based on the query strings

```
window.location.href
```

For example if i click the button **My Threads**, then the **href** will be

```
/threads?=myThreads=1
```

In this case i want to hide the button **My Threads**, based on the **href**.

**My question**

Is this a bad approach ? To make decisions based on the href.

Should i try a different approach ? Such as, passing data from the backend to to front end

Comment: You're not too far off, you just need to add a bit of logic into the component you're building out. Personally, I wouldn't let the href dictate the state of anything; you need to add some functionality in your component to handle the request instead. On 'mounted' you could default the state to all posts, and on button press you could filter that request using a method. Take a look at the official documentation for more info (this is very close to what you're trying to achieve): https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: Also, add a data property, i.e. 'queryType:' with v-if to hide or disable buttons depending on the query type.

Comment: If you mean to take an action based on the axios request then I can’t do that because I return a view from laravel and not a json  response. In addition to that some of the buttons that I use are not part of the Vue component but are part of the blade view.

Comment: Do you suggest then to change the whole structure in order to be able to return a Json response instead of a blade view ? If I do that, then I guess I can make axios requests and act upon the responses. However now that I’m thinking, even if I do that I will still need to access the query strings otherwise how can I manage the state of the buttons ?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm completely wrong here, but It sounds like you need to commit to one thing to handle the front end and one thing to handle the back end. Blade view sounds like a templating language for Laravel, which is PHP's version of Vue. I'd stick to using one of these, or fully commit to using Vue as your front end language and Laravel as your backend. Let me know if i've got the wrong end of the stick ;) I found this article might help you: https://vegibit.com/how-to-use-vuejs-with-laravel-blade/

Answer (score 1):

To get query params,

```
this.$route.query.myThreads
```

You can use the snippet to get the query params value.

To hide the button,

```
<a href="/threads?myThreads=1" v-if="query !== 1"> My Threads </a>
```

where `query` is containing the query params.

Comment: That’s a good tip because I wasn’t using vue to get the query strings. 

However, I am more concerned about but approach, whether it is correct or not. Any other approach is appreciated

Comment: Can you give some more idea about the scenario? so i can suggest alternative approach